# Is it possible force save zero integer values with Protocol Buffers in Java?

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, proto, protobuf-java

I'm using Protocol Buffers from Google in my Java projects.

When I define message like that:

```
message Event {
  int32 action = 1;
}
```

and save value zero as an action, then value zero won't be saved. It's able to save all integer values except for zero.

I even found it in my decompiled code generated by Protocol Buffers:

```java
...
public void writeTo(CodedOutputStream output) throws IOException {
  if (this.action_ != 0) {
    output.writeInt32(1, this.action_);
  }
  ...
}
```

Do you know, how can I force saving zeros? Or it's not possible and simply forbidden by Protocol Buffers design?

Comment: AFAIK you can change default value, so it will skip some other value.

Comment: @talex only in proto2; in proto3, explicit assignment tracking (presence tracking) has been added back - you can now use `optional int32 action = 1;` and it should work in the expected way

Comment: I've added more detail here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66891274/23354

Comment: So if I just add `optional` it will allow to save zeros? It's weird syntax for me because I don't want this field to be optional (in java sense). I want it to be required and have possibility to save zero value.

Comment: Same problem as @PiotrWittchen. What if I want it to be mandatory and have an explicit zero there?

Comment: That's the design of protocol buffers. You have to take it into consideration in your project.